# newAPIHadoopRDD Spark API doesn't retrieve unflushed data written to Hbase table

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hbase

Reading from an HBase table with a few hundred records that haven't been persisted (flushed) to HDFS doesn't show up in Spark. However, the records become visible after forced flush via Hbase shell or  system triggered flush (when size of Memstore crosses the configured threshold), and anything written after initial flush is immediately visible in Spark. Additionally, records in Memstore before flush are immediately visible to Hbase-client's scan api.

Note: We cannot use spark-hbase connector as schema is unknown beforehand. Hence, we resort to use newAPIHadoopRDD API

Spark read API

```scala
@transient val conf : Configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM);
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", ZOOKEEPER_PORT);
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "test")
val hbaseValueRDD = spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result]).map(x => x._2)
val hbaseValueFlattenedRDD = hbaseValueRDD.map(x => inputSplitter(x)).flatMap(x => x)
var rowDF = hbaseValueFlattenedRDD.toDF(COL_KEY, COL_VALUE)
```

We have tried passing custom scan object setting/unsetting several flags but none of them work. Below, we try to force Hbase Scan Api to read from replica-0 but to no avail.

```scala
// Function to convert Scan object to a base64 string
def convertScanToString(scan: Scan): String = {
  val proto = ProtobufUtil.toScan(scan)
  Base64.encodeBytes(proto.toByteArray)
}
@transient val scan = new Scan()
scan.setReplicaId(0)
@transient val scanStr = convertScanToString(scan)
@transient val conf : Configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM);
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", ZOOKEEPER_PORT);
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "test")
spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
```

Following Hbase client read API retrieves records stored in Memstore before flush as expected.

```scala
val table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(Bytes.toBytes("test")))
val scan = table.getScanner(new Scan())
scan.asScala.foreach(result => {
    println(result)
})
```

Comment: Where are you declaring connection object? Seems like you're not actually using Spark correctly, since you're converting to native Scala collections, which requires serializing all data back to the driver rather than distribute to Spark executors ... This code would be almost exact same if you use Hbase client directly. What do you mean by schema is unknown? Do you have no column families in Hbase table?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I updated the first snippet. Each row entry fetched from hbase is processed and later rowRDD is mapped to a DF. Work gets distributed to Spark executors.

> What do you mean by schema is unknown? 
We just have one column family with unknown number of columns. 

> Where are you declaring connection object?
If you are referring to the last code snippet, that's just an example showing how we are able to read unflushed data using hbase client api.

Comment: I haven't used Spark with HBase, but I feel like `spark-hbase` should be able to work with just a schema of `Array[Byte]` for any column. This is how the `spark-sql-kafka` functions work. Otherwise, `toDF` still needs a schema, in my experience